# How to create rectangles of variable size in Heatmap according to data given in json using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have made a Heatmap which represents the value by color intensity.how to create a Heatmap in which size of rectangles will be used to represent the value from json? I have tried the following code which is not giving the required output.

```
 <body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="dataset-picker">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var width=400,
     height=300,
     buckets=9,
     colors = ["#ccd9ff", "#99b3ff", "#668cff", "#3366ff", "#0040ff", "#0033cc", "#002699", "#002080", "#00134d"],

      datasets = [{
                 "day": 1,
                 "hour": 1,
                  "value1":16,
                  "value2":20

                  },

                  {
                      "day": 1,
                      "hour": 2,
                      "value1":23,
                      "value2":10

                  },

                  {
                      "day": 1,
                      "hour": 3,
                      "value1":13,
                      "value2":12

                  } 


               ];



       var canvas=d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
                   .attr("width",width)
                   .attr("height",height)
                   .append("g")


       var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(datasets, function (d) { return d.value2; })])
                .range(colors);



        var squares=canvas.selectAll("rect")
                     .data(datasets)
                     .enter()
                         .append("rect")
                          .attr("x", function (d,i) {return (i)* d.value1})
                          /*.attr("y",function (d,i) { return (i-1)* d.value2})*/
                          .attr("width",function(d){return d.value1 *10 })
                          .attr("height",function(d){return d.value2*10})
                          .attr("class", "hour bordered")

                          .style("fill", colors[0]);                          







</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant to do is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bc4um7pc/315/

You define the color range :

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0, buckets - 1])
                .range(colors);
```

Then choose a color from that range with a value from your dataset:

```
.style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.value1);});
```

since the range is from 0 to buckets -1 = 8, none of the `d.value1`'s were matching the range so i changed 1 `value1` to 3 so you can see the difference.

Comment: What I am trying to do is something like this http://jsfiddle.net/bc4um7pc/319/   I just wrote some sample code. I want rectangles of variable size like this in Heatmap.

Comment: @alice and you want to change their colors?

Comment: Yes I want to change their colors as well as size according to some value in json.

Comment: @alice did you figure out an approach?